# Get featured image URL by page id

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am using WordPress 3.4.1. I need to display the featured image of a page. How can I get the featured image URL by particular page ID. Any help?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Did you try anything? Its always helpful to share what you have tried.

```
$url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id) );
```

Or if you want to get the image by image size.

```
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id), 'thumbnail_size' );
$url = $src[0];
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

Comment: Actually, this is wrong - it suggests that you can get pass the size as a parameter, but that's not accurate.  Neither function accepts a parameter.

Comment: You can use `wp_get_attachment_image_url()` instead of `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` nowadays so you don't have to do that `$src[0]` part.

Answer (score 7):

As of Wordpress 4.4.0, we can use [get_the_post_thumbnail_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/):

```
$url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_id, 'thumbnail' );
```

Comment: Finally, it was about the time.