# Call featured image url

Tags: php, post-thumbnails, urls

How do I get the URL of my featured image?

I am using buffy and I can Call The URL of The post and so on, but can't figure out how to Call The URL of The featured image.

Comment: you can learn about  please visit https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76954/get-featured-image-url-by-page-id

Answer (score 1):

[`the_post_thumbnail()`](http://queryposts.com/function/the_post_thumbnail/) is highest level function for it, which will output complete HTML. If you need some lower level parts, digging deeper are nested:

- [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_post_thumbnail/)
- [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_get_attachment_image/)
- [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_get_attachment_image_src/)

Answer (score 0):

Hey by using   [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) to get the featured image url like this

```
<?php 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'large' );
    }
?>

<img src="<?php echo $large_image_url[0]; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call the following function to get the url of the featured image depending on the size you want to print :

```
the_post_thumbnail_url( $size );
```

the size variable might be either a string : (thumbnail, medium, large, full) or a precisized width and height (24*24).

You can learn more about it by visiting this url : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail_url